# jquery wait for on change to complete

Tags: jquery

I have a screen like this
[image]

If user checks that billing address is same as shipping address than I have to copy all data from billing address & fill into shipping address.

in the dropdowns first one is country & on change of it related states load in second dropdown.

When user checks "same address" thing, than I call

```
$('#payment_shipping_country').val($('#payment_country').val()).change()
```

Means take selected billing_country & place it in shipping_country than invoke change which will load states in shipping_state and than

```
$('#payment_shipping_state').val($('#payment_state').val()).change();
```

select shipping_state which was selected in billing_state.

Issue is that this select shipping state calls before shipping_states are loaded. It loads shipping_states but when code to select same shipping_state already run.

I tried multiple solutions like

```
$.when($('#payment_shipping_country').val($('#payment_country').val()).change()).then(function() {
   $('#payment_shipping_state').val($('#payment_state').val()).change();
});
```

But it never waits for shipping states to load.

Comment: yea... the only way you'll be able to wait on it is to gain access to the promise created by calling $.ajax. You'll have to store it somewhere that would allow you to access it from within the other event handler. Or... just have the other event handler return it and call that handler directly with .triggerHandler instead so that you can gain access to it's return value, the promise, and then chain off of it.

Comment: thanks, I am not very good with js, can you give me some example with code, or just some link with similar answer. 'll really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, you need to gain access to the promise created by calling $.ajax. One way of accomplishing this is to return the promise from the handler of the change event that performs the ajax request, and then trigger that handler so that you can access the promise and chain on it.

```
$('#payment_shipping_country').change(function () {
   // stuff...
   return $.ajax({/*... ajax settings ...*/});
})
```

later on,

```
$('#payment_shipping_country').val($('#payment_country').val())
.triggerHandler('change').then(function () {
  /* it's done! */
})
```

Comment: triggerHandler thing says "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `$('#payment_shipping_country')` change event with the addition of the `return` statement?

Comment: that change method was in a gem, I changed it was not updated in code. pulled things again & now working perfectly.
thanks a lot